# Winforms, how to make background of element transparent if it is placed on the web Browser?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am a beginner.
Problem is:
Even if BackColor is set to "web-transparent" it is really not transparent on some element such as a WebBrowser.
Looks like the color of mother element is applied.
Is there a way to make it fully transparent?
Or maybe I need to use some other element in this case? I just need to show a text and be able to drug it with a mouse.

Have a great day!

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBogZ.jpg)]

It will be nice if setting the BackColor to transparent will affect it in "human understanding" way)

Comment: Make the parent transparent.

Comment: Does Not work for me, unfortunately.

Comment: Kudos on your first post and thx for voting! It's really rare, however, for _anyone_ to be able to reproduce your issue or offer a solution without **1** seeing your code and **2** knowing _exactly_ what the issue is. So, please _before_ posting your separate follow up question about the font changes, have a quick look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask which will help us help you. IMO both questions are decent, but in the absence of **1** and **2** this one got downvoted (almost closed). Lots of people here can help, but will need to know exactly what you've tried in what order!

Comment: Thanks! I will folow the instruction!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that the reason a WinForms control appears transparent is that the "the background of a transparent Windows Forms control is painted by its parent" as explained in the MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-give-your-control-a-transparent-background). This means the parent control's background will be drawn into the Label *even if there's another control (you mentioned web browser) in between*.

The remedy is to change the *shape* of the Label control itself, by assigning a drawable `Region` that excludes the transparent pixels.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Change shape of Label control, removing transparent pixels.
        label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(label1.Width, label1.Height);
        label1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, label1.ClientRectangle);
        Region region = new Region(label1.ClientRectangle);
        for (int x = 0; x < label1.Width; x++) for (int y = 0; y < label1.Height; y++)
            {
                if (bitmap.GetPixel(x, y).A == 0)
                {
                    region.Exclude(new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1));
                }
            }
        label1.Region = region;
    }
}
```

[image: design mode and runtime]

---

*You say you want to drag it so be advised that a control coded this way will only detect a mouse click on the region of the control that still *exists* namely the text. But here's a sample solution for a transparent, draggable Label element that you can feel free to [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/transparent-over-web-browser.git) and experiment with.*

Comment: Thanks! Very interesting way to do object transparent)) But i like it!)

Comment: Well... I also need to change the font of the text. But it doesn't work after changing(

Comment: It also doesnt work if I try to call it not in moment of initialization((

Comment: It is ok! you can take your time.

Comment: I'm also wondering if you tried the sample code in my repo. Even though it doesn't address the font change specifically, having a clone on your device would make fixing it easier. Anyway, we'll get it all ironed out! Thanks for your patience.

Comment: No, but I just copied this code. As I can see it is the same you write on your repo. As I can see no more code that is related to my issue on your repo. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's fine if you copied it from the repo as long as you picked up the `DragHelper` class and can drag the `label element` around and it does the highlighting and color changing.

Comment: I use another way to move the label. Does it affect the transparency? Curently problem is: "If I move the code you introduced here to the button_click event it doesnt work". Now I am going to explore you repo.

Comment: Same. If I use your repo and just move code from main to button_click it doesn`t work. I think this is a main problem now. [screenshot](https://ibb.co/HDQwRxT)

Comment: Ok, I just have to ask this because you described yourself as a beginner:  You _are_ familiar with the process of "cloning a repo", yes?  The thing is, the repo code _works_ so did you clone it or copy code from it?

Comment: Advice is the same though. We're definitely at a point where we need to see your code in order to diagnose anything. So, really, please _do_ consider making a new question and showing what you've tried so far.

Comment: I clone your repo. Than I move code that makes label transparent to evet that called when button is pressed and in this case it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Need I to create absolytely new question?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that it works in the cloned solution but fails after you move that code into yours?

Comment: I just need to see your code somehow. Either in a new question or if you have a GitHub account I'd be willing to look at _your_ repo if you wanted to make one. Those are our two options.

Comment: No. Your code is on the public MainForm() method. It means it will be executed once when form is starts. But how to force it to execute this code when I click button? If just cntrl+x this code and then cntrl+v it to the buttton_click method it doesnt work. You can see, how I modify your code in the screenshot I send earlier. ![example with screenshot](https://ibb.co/HDQwRxT) My code is almost the same. Ok I will create new question. Thank you very much!)