# How to add a control to form1 designer by code and make the control to be in the front?

Tags: c#, winforms

When I drag the control in the designer of form1 from the toolbox the control is in the front:

The ChromiumWebBrowser control is on the top of everything when dragging it from the toolbox:

[image: chromiumwebbrowser is on the top]

The problem is that I don't want the control to be on top of everything if I'm not running the application and clicking a button.  I want the control to be in the form1 designer but not on the top.

so, I thought to create the control by code:

```
private void btnShowOnGoogleMaps_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChromiumWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser1 = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
            chromiumWebBrowser1.Size  = new Size(500,500);
            chromiumWebBrowser1.Show();
            chromiumWebBrowser1.Load("D:\\Csharp Projects\\Weather\\map.html");
        }
```

but with the code when I click the button the control is in the back.  no matter what I tried.

I tried to add this line:

```
chromiumWebBrowser1.BringToFront();
```

but it didn't change much.
this is the control after clicking the button:

you can see the control (with the map) on the left side of the form1 on the left edge and the control is behind everything else.

I marked with red ellipse the control to show where it is hiding behind.

[image: the control is on the left side edge of form1 behind everything]

Comment: Can you take a look at this answer and see if it helps solve your problem? "_In WinForms you can show any control (e.g. PictureBox) over any other control (e.g. WebView2) by adding the former to the Controls collection of the latter._" https://stackoverflow.com/a/75460185/5438626

Answer (score 0):

Is there a ZOrder function for this control? Usually you can just do control.ZOrder(0) to bring the control in front.